# i am using nextjs and trying to fetch data from an api from backend but the is returned undefined and i am not seeing a request in the network

Tags: next.js

```
  export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/courses");
       if (!res.ok) {
           throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
        
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        return { props: { data } };
      } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    }

    const PopularCourses = ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Popular Course</h1>
          {data?.map((course) => (
            <div key={course.id}>
              <h1>{course.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default PopularCourses;
```

i am getting that the data is undefined in the terminal and i tried fetching data different ways but still have the same result